Different infinitves

It is important to work now

It is important to be working now


I am asked by someone to explain the difference between these two. To me, there is almost no difference just 2 could emphasize that it is important to be already working at this moment. Correct?

now minimizes the difference.

This question is similar to: 'to do something' vs. 'to be doing something'. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The negative infinitive form is: It's important for work-life balance not to work every day.

to work is just a purpose. The idea.

to be working is the actual activity of doing work.
